# Jpgraph position text at certain x-value position

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm using JPGraph with a simple Line plot.

It's possible to create a text or image and position it vertically and horizontally centered on a point of my line?

Something like:

```
$txt = new Text("hello");
$txt->SetPosition????("center",$p1->$index,$shift_x,$shift_y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to position the text on a specific point in the graph area by

```
$txt->SetScalePos(x, y);
```

where x and y are the coordinations on the X and Y axis.